# How can we create multiple consumer(on various machines) using Kafka's API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to create Producer on my local machine and Consumer some another machine , I am successfully able to send messages through Producer but I cannot consume messages on another machine ?
I have used Kafka's API to write my java code.

Please can anyone help ?

```
This is my server.properties of Kafka on my local machine:
broker.id=0
log.dir=C:/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

Comment: Is the producer on the same machine where Kafka + Zookeeper are running ? Can you provide the consumer configuration please ?

Comment: Is that it for server.properties? No listener config or advertised.host.name or anything else? Also (unrelated) that version of Kafka is 2 years old. Any reason you are not running 0.11 since it's backwards compatible with 0.9?